# Project Suggestions for a Complexity Class

Tags: complexity-theory, p-np

I'm taking a 400-level class on Complexity and Problem Solving. The final project is to implement a problem that has to do with P and NP. Unfortunately, the teacher has been inexcusably vague about the boundaries of the project.

So I just thought I'd ask on here to see if anyone has a suggestion for a moderately-difficult problem that I might implement. I understand this question is quite vague, but I'd be interested to hear if anybody has a favorite problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **TSP, VRP or curriculum course scheduling**.

You 'll find links to each of those problem definitions and datasets in [this metaheuristics framework manual](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#useCasesAndExamples).